# Reserve fixed RAM memory region as a block device ( with a given start physical address)

Tags: linux, memory, ramdisk

There have been a lot of questions about RAM Disks and I am aware of ramfs and tmpfs which allow the use of ram as a block device. However my interest is in using a fixed memory address range as a block device.

This arises from the necessity to use non-volatile RAM available in my system. I have 6GB of RAM available, and 8GB of non-volatile RAM present. The output of /proc/iomem gives me the following

100000000-17fffffff : System RAM

180000000-37fffffff : reserved

Here the region from 6GB to 14GB corresponds to the Non-volatile RAM region which is marked by the E820 BIOS memory map as reserved. My main intention is to use this NVRAM as a block device in linux. This is useful for testing NVRAM systems. Is there any linux command already present which would allow me to use this region as a block device, or do I have to write my own kernel device driver to facilitate the same?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this?

Comment: It provides an easy way to test filesystems designed for Non-Volatile RAM on linux.

Comment: @qstack Did you ever get this working? I have a similar issue and would value any thoughts you have: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634988/allocate-ram-block-device-faster-than-linux-kernel-can-normally-allocate-memory

Comment: I believe you already have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on device drivers, however here are some pointers for your R&D:

1. if memory is marked as "reserved", the OS cannot touch it; you will have to find a way to either have the BIOS mark it as available to the OS, or use direct low-level [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)s to [control it](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html)
2. if Linux could *see* the memory, you still would not have an easy way to prevent Linux from using it as any other block of RAM; an attempt could be tried by marking such RAM as "bad" and then modifying the kernel to still make a special use out of it (please check kernel documentation regarding this, it has changed *a lot* since last time I hacked into it and it's evolving at a great speed)
3. considering the above as a preliminary (and non-definitive nor exhaustive) feasibility study, I would say writing your ramdisk blockdevice driver is the most sane option in your case, and perhaps you should contribute it back to Linux kernel and/or team up with people already trying this (perhaps a better place for this question is the [Linux Kernel Mailing list](https://lkml.org/), if you haven't yet posted there)

Some other relevant sources:

- [Current ramdisk driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/target/target_core_rd.c)
- [A somewhat old (2005) document about block drivers](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch16.pdf)
- [A simple block driver for Linux Kernel 2.6.31](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/05/04/a-simple-block-driver-for-linux-kernel-2-6-31/comment-page-2/) (careful: **a lot** has changed in time)

Answer (score 2):

Before the introduction of `tmpfs` / `initramfs` there was `ramdisk`used to load the `initrd`images, a pre-defined fixed size block devices, I think contiguous, at least on earlier implementations.

The block driver itself doesn't have parameters for the memory address, only the size, but the kernel used to load initrd images at a pre-defined address (by config) so a peek into *main* / *init* kernel code could help (I would be surprised if *ramdisk* aren't supported anymore for initrd but since *initramfs* is around, a lot of years now, never used *ramdisk* anymore).

The driver source was [drivers/block/rd.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/block/rd.c?v=2.4.37), if I see correctly now is [drivers/block/brd.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/block/brd.c) .

Else, looking for *ramdisk* I found an implementation that looks interesting:

[Disk on RAM — Playing with Block Drivers](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/02/device-drivers-disk-on-ram-block-drivers/)